# How to prove if subgroups are Cyclic then Group is Cyclic too?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

**The duplicate question doesn't really answer my problem.**

Given $G$ with order of 15.
$G_3$ and $G_5$ are **the only** sub-groups of $G$ with order of 3 and 5 respectively. (In other words, there could be other sub-groups with different order but none with order 3 that's not $G_3$).

I want to prove that $G$ is Cyclic group.

---

**My try:**

To prove that $G$ is Cyclic group I was searching for $a$ in $G$ such that: $a^{|G|}=a^{15}=e$

3 and 5 are prime numbers so $G_3$ and $G_5$ are both Cyclic groups. ie, there are $b$ in $G_3$ and $c$ in $G_5$ such that: $b^3=e, c^5=e$.

if $b=c$ then we finished, since our $a$ would be $bc$ but that's not always correct to assume this equality...

Any help?

Comment: This is the standard way to prove that every group of order $15$ is cyclic. See the duplicates how to finish it. We have $G=G_3\times G_5\cong C_{15}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry that didn't help. I don't understand what this multiplication means and why it solves my problem.

Comment: Not every product of two primes is like 15. For example, there is a non-Abelian group of order 21, whose subgroups ( apart from itself, of course) are cyclic (clearly, as 3 and 7 are primes).

Comment: Algo, it solves your problem, because it shows that every group of order $15$ is the direct product of its unique subgroups $G_3$ and $G_5$. So it must be cyclic by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how to prove =? plus why once I prove this I finish? I don't understand....